# Application_Error not working in production server

Tags: asp.net, iis

Application_Error was not firing on production server. but its working in our local server and other amazon server. in our local server have windows7 OS and IIS (7.5)version, but the production server have Windows8 and IIS (8+) version. any one have any idea.

```
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
      Exception  ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

      string cls = ex.TargetSite.DeclaringType.Name;
      string mtd = ex.TargetSite.Name;

        string ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        string page = Request.Path;
        string url = Request.PhysicalPath;
        string StackTrace = "";
        string inputdata = "";


        if (ErrorMessage != "File does not exist.")
        {
             StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
             foreach (string i in Session.Contents)
             {
                 if (Session[i] != null)
                 {
                     if (inputdata != "")
                     {
                         inputdata = inputdata + " , [" + i + "] = " + Session[i].ToString();
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         inputdata = "[" + i + "] = " + Session[i].ToString();
                     }
                 }
             }

            string flg = objBus.insertException(page, "", ErrorMessage, StackTrace, "", url, Session["UserID"].ToString(), inputdata,"");
            //string flg = "0";


            //Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx?errorId=" + flg, false);
            Server.Transfer("~/ErrorPage.aspx?errorId=" + flg, false);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score -2):

When you publish try to enable "Precompile during publish", this should include PrecompiledApp.config in publish folder